# How to use router link in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

i am designing a login form using vuetify, i want to make one option 'forgot password', where after clicking 'forgot password' it should redirect to forgot password page, i tried using router-link,nuxt-link, tag, and vuejs events(@click)and in function i called this.$router.push('forgotPassword'). but nothing works. please help me.

these are the following options i tried.

```
<template>
<v-col cols="6">
   <div @click="changeRouter()">Forgot Password?</div>
   <a href="../forgotPassword">Forgot Password?</a>
   <v-list-item :to="{path: '/forgotPassword'}">Forgot Password?</v-list-item> 
   <router-link :to="{ path:'/forgotPassword', name: 'forgotPassword' }">Forgot Password</router-link>
</v-col>
</template>
<script>
changeRouter(){
      this.$router.push({path: "/forgotPassword"});
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about your setup? Or what error you get?
Besides, check the manual of Nuxt on how to use the router: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing/#nested-routes
And finally, first try to just use nuxt-link with a simple route in to like so: <nuxt-link to="/forgotPassword">Link</nuxt-link>

Comment: Hi @crslp i am not getting any error, the forgot password option is disabled, when i am clicking it nothing is happening. And my setup is not complex, simple setup i have done

Comment: If `changeRouter()` does not work - it means there is something wrong with your VueRouter's config. Check it.

Comment: First off, double check the route in your Vue devtools, make sure that it's there. Then, use a simple `button` with a `@click="$router.push({ name: 'forget-password-name-or-whatever' })"`. Also, what do you mean by `the forgot password option is disabled`? Do you have a [repro] for that one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

v-list-item is a wrapper for router-link ..
So just the v-list-item with the :to should work.
You have it double now.